# Get upper triangular matrix and storing positions of non-zero elements in incidence matrix efficiently for large datasets in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

Heyy!

I have 100s of csv files with mapped numbers:

Here is a snapshot of one of the input files..

```
0        1
16778   11984
16786   16796
.         .
.         .
16786   16799
16786   10937
16791   16801

(count of each column -> 50,000)
```

I am creating incidence matrix from these mapped numbers using this logic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

im_list = []
for filename in glob.iglob('input_file_path/*.csv', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
  
    df = pd.read_csv(filename) ## creating df of the ip csv file
    Inc_matrix = np.zeros((20000,20000)) # creating matrix of all zeros with required shape
    
    ## logic for getting the 0s matrix populated if the mapping exist in the input files
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
      print(i)
      Inc_matrix[df['0'][i], df['1'][i]] = 1
      Inc_matrix[df['1'][i], df['0'][i]] = 1
      ## in order to be efficient I am working with only required amount of information
      ## performing other required steps once I get the incidence matrix
      upper = np.triu(Inc_matrix) # creating upper triangular matrix 
      nonzero = np.flatnonzero(Inc_matrix) # saving only the positions of non-zero elements
      print(nonzero.shape)
      
    im_list.append(nonzero)
```

However, while using `np.triu` and `np.flatnonzero` is extremely time intensive (more than 10 hours for running one csv file), atleast in this case.

Any more efficient ways (feedback/suggestion) to undergo this steps in this loop will be helpful.

PS: I am using this logic on only 10-15 files since...., even if I use 20 files to start with (out of a few 100 files), this is the error I am encountering: `numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.10 GiB for an array with shape (20000, 20000) and data type float64`
Any suggestions to overcome this error would be helful as well.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Shouldn't `im_list.append(nonzero)` be in the innermost loop? Otherwise you do not need to compute `upper` and `nonzero` in the innermost loop. Still, even with that `upper` is not read so it is useless in the code and can be safely remove. Did I missed something?

Comment: You can compute the positions of nonzero entries without ever computing the incidence matrix.

Comment: Appreciate you comment, Mihai. The task I am performing is based on Incidence matrices, this is the reason I'm creating the matrix first.